# Barcode not printing properly in zebra direct thermal printer

Tags: javascript, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing

I have a barcode printed webpage, which i have created using javascript library. its printing properly in normal A4 printer, but when im trying to pring its in zebra GD420 (direct thermal) barcode printer, its printing blank page, In zebra user guide they instruct to send zpl commands like," ^XA^FO50,50^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD123456^FS^XZ "  and not getting that, how can use it in my code ? 
One more think that my client is testing it(printing barcode in barcode printer) remotely.
So is there any configuration settings needed for this?

Please find attached screen shot my barcode printing preview.

[image]

i have writte a javascript function for printing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printprocess(numid) {


    for(var i=0;i<numid;i++){
      $("#barcodeTarget").html("");
      var productbarcode=document.getElementById("productbarcode"+i).value;
      var productbarcodevariant=document.getElementById("productbarcodevariant"+i).value;
      var productvariantvalue=document.getElementById("productvariantvalue"+i).value;
      var productprice=document.getElementById("productprice"+i).value;
      var productquantity=document.getElementById("productquantity"+i).value;

      var alstuf=productbarcode+"---"+productbarcodevariant+"------"+productvariantvalue+"---"+productprice+"------"+productquantity;

      if(productquantity!="0"){
    var par1=productbarcodevariant;
    var par2=productvariantvalue;
    var par3=productprice;
    var timu= productquantity;
    var value =productbarcode;
    var renderer ="bmp";
    var btype = "code128";
    var quietZone = false;
    var settings = {
      output:renderer,
      bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
      color: "#000000",
      barWidth: "1",
      barHeight: "40",
      moduleSize: "1",
      posX: "1",
      posY: "1",
      addQuietZone: "1"
    };
    $("#barcodeTarget").html("").show().barcode(value, btype, settings);
    for(var x=0;x<productquantity;x++){
      var Mybarcode = document.getElementById('barcodeTarget').innerHTML;
      console.log(Mybarcode);
      var adtext='<div  style="background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 250px;font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;margin: 200px 0px 200px -70px; -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);-o-transform: rotate(90deg);-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(90deg);">     '+par1+': '+par2+'<br/>Price : '+par3+' '+Mybarcode+'   </div>';
      $("#barcodelist").append(adtext);
    }
      }
    }
    var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
    disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=200, height=600, left=100, top=25"; 
    var content_vlue = document.getElementById("barcodelist").innerHTML; 
    var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
    docprint.document.open();
    docprint.document.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
    docprint.document.write('<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><style type="text/css"> @media (max-width: 4in) {    @page {      size: A4;    }  }</style></head>');
    docprint.document.write('<body onLoad="self.print()">');
    docprint.document.write(content_vlue);          
    docprint.document.write('</html>'); 
    docprint.document.close(); 
    docprint.focus(); 
    docprint.print(); 
    $("#barcodeTarget").hide()
    return false;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to create a string using the ZPL style coding and then shoot that directly at the printer. It looks like you are sending html to the device.

Comment: @DouglasAnderson How to convert above code to Zpl style coding?

Comment: Just build a large string that looks like: ^XA^FO50,50^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD123456^FS^XZ and then pass that to the printer directly>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use zebra programming language to send data on barcode printer, as @douglas ,mentioned you have to make zpl string like   ^XA^FO50,50^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD123456^FS^XZ
to convert the instruction . check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600838/writing-program-printing-ean13-barcode-in-intermec-printer) for write code in zpl

Answer (score 1):

create an object of barcode printer class  in zebra programming language. like

```
BarCodeField barcode = new BarCodeField("barcode",
                                         10, // X Position in dots 
                                         10, // Y Position in dots 
                                         Printer.ALIGN_BOTTOM_LEFT, // Alignment
                                         Printer.DIR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT,// Direction
                                         BarCodeField.TYPE_EAN_13,// barcode type
                                         56, //barcode height
                                         1, // wideRatio
                                         3, // narrowRatio
                                         1,//Magnification
                                        "3442648507010"); // barcode expression
```